# Subprocess.check_output or xclip -o hanging

Tags: python, xclip

On Linux mint I'm using the following code to monitor my clipboard:

```
last_clip = ''
try:
    while True:
        clip_contents = subprocess.check_output(['xclip', '-o'])
        if clip_contents != last_clip:
           #write clip_contents to file
        time.sleep(0.5)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print(" Quitting...")
```

It works great, except for every so often it hangs up. I'm fairly sure it's on the `check_output` line, because `ps aux` shows that `xclip -o` is an active process. And when I kill it with `-INT` or `-HUP` I get this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get.py", line 16, in <module>
    clip_contents = subprocess.check_output(['xclip', '-o'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 544, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['xclip', '-o']' returned non-zero exit status -1
```

Am *I* Doing something wrong, or is there something buggy going on here?